# Link Redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all type of links like that :

www.sitename.com/link1-XXX.html

to

www.sitename.com/link1-XXX/

I don't want to redirect all .html links. I want to redirect all html links which end with XXX.

Solution :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)XXX\.html$ /$XXX/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specified the question, just told us what you want to do, not what is your problem...

if your problem is, that you dont know how to redirect only links like you described, then put this in your .htaccess with RewriteEngine on:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)-XXX\.html?$ /$1-XXX/ [L,QSA]
```

I did not really tested this regex..
It should take anything that end with /"something"-XXX.htm and /"something"-XXX.html and redirect it to subaddr named as "something"-XXX/

if you would need append some GET params to the processed url, you should change the regex so it ends like this:

```
...html?(.*)$
```

meaning, there can be anything after htm or html

Comment: Thanksyou for answer. But it didnt work. My links template is like that : www.sitename.com/movie-name-1-season-4-episode.html . So there is - character between words and it ends with episode word.

Comment: This code has worked for me. Thanks you! RewriteRule ^(.*)episode\.html$ /$episode/ [R=301,L]